# Extracting values from certain fields in a json api request. (Ruby)

Tags: json, ruby, api, sinatra

Attempting to extract the field "searched_count" in Udemy's API, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it will be highly appreciated. I'm using Sinatra and parsing the api request using net/http.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

def get_search_count(term)

    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/search-suggestions?q=java'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    JSON.parse(response)

    return response ["results"][0]["searched_count"]

end


get '/' do
    return get_search_count("java")
end
```

I'm attempting to display the number on the web page. I don't receive any errors while I'm running it, but I can't tell if I'm actually receiving feedback from the request.

If it helps, here's a snippet from the json file:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "_class": "search_log",
            "id": 88,
            "phrase": "java",
            "searched_count": 3749730,
            "url": "/courses/search/?q=java"
        },
```

---

Edit: Here's my attempt at showing it on the web page. Located in index.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= @title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= @headline %></h1>
        <p><%= @paragraph %></p>
        <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
            Search Term: <input type="text" name="term"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, my updated code in web.rb :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

def get_search_count(term)
    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/search-suggestions?q=java'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)

    return parsed_response ["results"][0]["searched_count"]
end


get '/' do
    return get_search_count("java")
end

get '/term' do
    erb :index
end

get '/action_page.php' do
    return get_search_count(params[:name])
end
```

Comment: @SimpleLime I tried implementing it with what I could find online, but I don't think I'm using the right syntax. May you elaborate further?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the method to something like this

```
  def get_search_count(term)
    url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/search-suggestions?q=java'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)

    return parsed_response ["results"][0]["searched_count"]
end
```

NB:If you are getting the response properly it will work.

Comment: This runs as well, but it's not returning a value to me on the screen (web page). Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How you are showing this value in the web page?Do you have any related code?

Comment: Okay, sorry. I have updated my code with my attempt to post it on the web page. It can be found at the bottom of my original post as an edit. I posted html code that is found in a file labeled index.erb

Comment: I'm still new at this, so some of the syntax may be very wrong. I tried learning off of various blogs.

Comment: @AlexSalinas I can see some php web pages you are referring in the form to submit.Before going into the deep, please have a basic understanding of how the sinatra application works. This tutorial  will give you a basic understanding.https://www.sitepoint.com/just-do-it-learn-sinatra-i/